# 3 domains 1 A record

Tags: domain-name-system

I have 3 domains that point to the same server.
A.com
B.com
C.com

I want to make it easy to change IP address in one place if I need to. Is it possible to create 1 A record.

can I make an A record for A.com and then create CNAME records for any hosts I need on A.com B.com and C.com?

This way if I need to change IP address I only have to change 1 A record. Is this possible and/or recommended?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK this would only work if you want to create the CNAME-records for subdomains like www.B.com and www.C.com. If you would like to use CNAMEs for the root-domain (e.g. B.com) this is not possible, they have to be A-records.

So this is possible:

- www.A.com -> IP
- www.B.com -> CNAME www.A.com
- www.B.com -> CNAME www.A.com

This is **not** possible:

- A.com -> IP
- B.com -> CNAME A.com
- B.com -> CNAME A.com

Comment: The reason for that being that you cannot mix CNAME RRs with any other RR type such as SOA, NS, TXT (for SPF, etc.), MX and so on; it would create an ambiguity. Let's say you have `a.com SOA ...`, `a.com CNAME b.com` and `b.com MX mx.c.com` and now someone asks for `a.com MX`. What should be the response, as `a.com` doesn't have a MX record defined?